# Pandas: Filtering column that is dtype of object (it has int and string values) via a list?

Tags: pandas, filtering

I have an example DF below (I would have shared the code but I could not load in a column to replicate the issue ie int and strings in the the object column A).

I want to just filter and return a df that has the following values, but the problem is when I do so - it returns an empty data frame despite it having the values. I have tried to convert it all to strings but same result of an empty data frame. Any ideas?

this is what I get when I print the df

```
COL_A      COL_B
2A001      Red
75101      Orange
75102      Grey
75104      Pink
```

-> COL_A dtype = object

filters_string = ['75101', '75102', '75103', '75104']

filters_int = [75101, 75102, 75103, 75104]

Approach 1:

```
df['COL_A'] = df['COL_A'].astype(str)

# Filter for column in the target list
filtered_df = df[df['COL_A'].isin(filters_string)]
```

Approach 2:

```
df['COL_A'] = df['COL_A'].astype(str)

# Filter for column in the target list
filtered_df = df[df['COL_A'].isin(filters_int)]
```

They both return empty dataframes?

Comment: Object doesn't mean strings, you can also have integers. Your first approach works fine and returns 3 rows

Comment: Try: `df[df['COL_A'].str.strip().isin(filters_string)]`

Comment: still no dice, its hard because I can't share the exact file. But the filter operation works for the original dataframe that I read in but when I merge it with another dataframe ( I can see that the desired COL_A values are in the merged df) when I filter it, it resolves to 0, same with if I filter it in the df before then the merge resolves to 0

Comment: Well, difficult to debug without the real data...

Comment: `COL_A` seems to have a hex number, Currently, you are doing int to str comparison... Convert your `filters_int` to str, and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be working fine. Perhaps your code is returning an empty dataframe because `'COL_A'` might have trailing or leading `' '` (whitespaces) but without looking at your data it's impossible to know for sure.

The code below is similar to your original implementation. The two major differences are that the below implementation accounts for trailing and leading whitespaces, removing them prior to comparing `'COL_A'` with the `filters_string` list, and it filters `'COL_A'` values that either exist inside `filters_string` **OR** `filters_int` lists.

```py
import pandas as pd


# Lists of values to use for filtering the 'COL_A' column on our dataframe
filters_string = ['75101', '75102', '75103', '75104']
filters_int = [75101, 75102, 75103, 75104]

# Creating the dataframe to test our logic
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["2A001", "Red"],
        [" 75101", "Orange"],
        ["  75102  ", "Grey"],
        [" 75104", "Pink"],
    ],
    columns = ["COL_A", "COL_B"]
)

# Filter 'COL_A' column for values that are on either `filters_string` OR `filters_int` lists.
# NOTE: The `|` operator is the pandas equivalent to `OR`.
#       Before comparing 'COL_A' with the `filters_string` list, we convert all its values to strings.
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['COL_A'].astype(str).str.strip().isin(filters_string)) | (df['COL_A'].isin(filters_int)), :]
filtered_df
# Returns:
#
#    COL_A   COL_B
# 1  75101  Orange
# 2  75102    Grey
# 3  75104    Pink
```